# How to use android:layout_weight consistently for all screensizes

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have an app that uses android:layout_weight for header spacing, however when I view the app on a different screensize the spacing change (not aligned with the row data below).

I have 5 headers, but the headers don't align correctly for all devices.

How can I ensure I use android:layout_weight to achieve a common spacing layout that can work on all screensizes?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listTitles"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/table_heading"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="POS"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BIRTH"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="SCORE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="POINTS"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="ROUND"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I believe when you use a layout_weight you need to set either the layout_width or layout_height (which ever you are basing on weight) to a value of 0dp

Comment: Does the layout for rows below have the same `layout_weight` as the headers?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. When using `layout_weight`, you must set `layout_width` to `0dp`.
2. The rows in your table or `ListView` must have the same `layout_weight` and `layout_width` values.

Answer (score -2):

Set the parent LinearLayout weight_sum to 7 since all the TextView space occupied is equal to 7

Change the layout_width of all the TextView to 0dp. This is a modify version

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listTitles"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/table_heading"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:weightSum="7"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="POS"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BIRTH"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="SCORE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="POINTS"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="ROUND"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is not necessary to set the `weight_sum`. Android calculates this automatically.

Comment: Yes, but it is a personal preference

Comment: It also doesn't address the actual problem in the question.

Comment: It does because if it does not have any use it should have been removed. Beside there is nothing wrong where I used it.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong. But it is unlikely that it actually fixes the layout problems that the OP is asking about because the behavior is identical to the original layout.

Comment: Also `weight_sum` **does** have uses. In particular, it is helpful when you do not include `layout_weight` on one or more child views. When all of the child views have a `layout_weight`, `layout_sum` is unnecessary.

Comment: I think @Code-Apprentice is saying the `weighted_sum` part does not address the question.  However, @NollyJ is talking about the `layout_width`s.  The `weighted_sum` part of the answer IS irrelevant, but the widths matter.  Some of the widths are `wrap_content` and others are hardcoded `xxdp`.  They are pretty different from `0dp` which is I'm pretty sure is part of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) on using `layout_weight`.   That said, its moot unless the data table, which we have not seen, is formatted the same way.

Comment: @MiaoLiu Good point. The part of this answer regarding `layout_width` is certainly relevant as well as the layout for the other rows.